# Implement efficient function mapping with partial parameters filled

Tags: python, python-3.x, pattern-matching, closures

I have a collection of functions, each with different parameters:

```py
def f1(x, y, z):
    pass

def f2(x, y):
    pass

def f3(x, y, z, w):
    pass

def f4(x, y, z):
    pass

...
```

Then, I have a function that selects different parameters based on the value of `effect_type`.

```py
def func(x, effect_type: int): 
     if effect_type == 1: 
         f1(x, y=1, z=2)
     elif effect_type == 2:
         f2(x, y=1.2)
     elif effect_type == 3:
         f3(x, y=2, z=3, w=4)
     elif effect_type == 4:
         f4(x, y=3, z=1)
     elif effect_type == 5:
         f4(x, y=10, z=0)
     ...
     elif effect_type == 1000:
         ...
     else:
         ...
```

However, this implementation is inefficient as the time complexity of the `if-else` structure is O(*n*), where *n* is the number of cases.

In Java, I could use `switch` to optimize it, since Java's `switch` has a time complexity of O(1) (using a [hashtable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.tableswitch)) or O(log *n*) (using [binary search](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.lookupswitch)). However, Python does not have a comparable feature, as its pattern match still has a time complexity of O(*n*).

Now, I would like to implement a function dictionary or list that allows me to use the following format:

```py
func_map[effect_type](x)
```

How should I implement this `func_map` (something like following)?

```py
func_map = {
    1 : f1(?, y=1, z=2), 
    2 : f2(?, y=1.2),
    3 : f3(?, y=2, z=3, w=4),
    4 : f4(?, y=3, z=1),
    5 : f4(?, y=10, z=0),
    ...
}
```

Comment: How many functions do you expect to have? This sounds like premature optimization. But please note, if you do use a dictionary, define the dictionary outside the function or else the literal will get re-evaluated each time, removing the time complexity benefit and moreover, will be slower than your `if-elif` if I had to guess